# Ignoring mouseenter/mouseout events on children of same element in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, mouseover

I am using this menu (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/) in my website and I modified it slightly. Instead of using the button to show and hide the menu I want to show the menu when the mouse enters a region of the menu and disappears when the mouse leaves the menu. I managed to achieve showing the menu on `mouseenter`, however, whenever hovering over a child the menu just keeps showing and hiding itself. The JS code can be seen in the snippet below.

```
    showLeft.onmouseover = function() {
        classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
        classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    };
```

I made some research and from what I understood is that this phenomenon is referred to as 'bubbling' and I tried filtering the trigger of the event by the source of the event however I was not successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is caused by event bubbling as you identified.

The simplest way to solve your problem is to use jQuery, which specifically handles this case through its [`mouseenter/mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) events.

```
$(elem).on("mouseenter", function() {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, however I had to use a slightly different syntax

 $(menuLeft).mouseenter(function() {
    //code
 });